# How to retrieve image in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Here is my code,

```
string constring = @"Data Source=MUZAFFAR_ALI801\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=imageform;Integrated Security=True;";
SqlConnection condatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT id, Source, Channel, Category, Image, url, Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3
                                            FROM Uploads", condatabase);

        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = sc;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I have a database with image column. I want to retrieve image in datagridview like I saved in SQL Database in numbers but I faced the error.

Here is the screen shot of error:

[image]

Comment: not enough info in your question. What error did you receive? Where is the front end code? Is that image field binary data? file path?

Comment: `but i faced the error` Any you think we have crystal ball to see the error?

Comment: this is my first post in stackoverflow that's why i don't know how to add image.

Comment: I want to retirive all the fields from database to datagridview all things are showing but the image column is not showing..
Here is the screen shot of error:
http://i.imgur.com/LLBJOlV.png

Comment: It would be better if you added the error as text rather than an image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure about the direct fill method you are using `DataAdapter`, but I just tried after checking your error snapshot and it worked.

**Step 1**:

Inserted a datagridview on a win form.

**Step 2**:

Used the following code for image retrieval for each object (converting the image in binary is the key here, and then attach it to the datasource / bindingsource).

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectList.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Image img = //Get your image;
        Byte[] result = (Byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(img, typeof(Byte[]));
        Object.Image = result;
    }
    catch
    { }
}

bindingSource1.DataSource = objectList;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```